# Identify mistake in Sentence if any

Tags: grammaticality

By the time Julia Roberts was 23, she had won two academy award nominations, she had also become the world's most popular female actress.

Comment: What do you think the mistake is?

Comment: I am not sure that's why i have asked

Comment: Female actress is a tautology. If she's an actress, she's female. These days the complication is that the word "actress" has become a gender issue. It is going out of fashion in some quarters like authoress and numerous others. Many actresses now refer to themselves as actors. In that case, you could refer to Julia Roberts as a female actor although the name gives it away. I should also prefer a semi-colon or stop after "nominations".

Comment: I am just asking is there any grammatical mistake in this or not?

I am not getting your point.@Roland

Comment: How do you know  "she had also become the world's most popular female actress"? Did you ask everyone in the world? Anyway, we don't do proofreading questions here. You need to identify a specific concern.

Comment: @RounakLahoti - as Alan Carmack said, ELL doesn't just do proofreading.  We want you to identify what you think the problem is because you have to show that you've done some work on this, and we can help you better if we know exactly what's confusing you.

Comment: one of my friend says there will be a mistake in using had

but i don't think..

Comment: otherwise my answer is there is no problem in sentence.

Comment: The mistake is that it is a 'run-on' sentence. There are two main clauses that are separated by only a comma. A heavier punctuation mark such as a full stop, semi-colon or perhaps a dash is required.

Comment: @BillJ i think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments, the language mistakes in the sentence are :

1. run-on sentence : "She had also.." should be the start of a new sentence -  *identified by BillJ*.
2. tautology : an actress is necessarily female, so the adjective "female" is redundant - *identified by Ronald Sole*.

"She had won" and "she had also become" are grammatically correct.